# Advance search form

Tags: php, ajax

Maybe is a stupid question but i really need this.

I need to find a good solution for my advance search form with many selectboxes and checkboxes.

So this is the scenery:

step 1.When the user change the selectedbox value make a select in database with the selected values;
step 2.When the user check a checkbox the script need to make another select based on the selected value from the first step.
I need to use PDO and AJAX.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please show us your code first

Comment: Like this http://www.vola.ro/ search form with many tables

Comment: just do it with an array, php explode the choices and then query the database on keyup/click. Your logic is there just break them up into manageable bits

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your amount of checkboxes you could do something like the following beneath.

For example we take festivals and concerts for our selectbox

```
<select>
    <option value="0">Click me</option>
    <option value="1">Festivals</option>
    <option value="2">Concerts</option>
</select>
```

In our Database we create a table "events".(again this is just an example because you have not provided a set amount of code)
In events we have the columns:

```
event_id
event_name
```

And to put this in our working example we would have:

```
--------------------------
| event_id | event_name |
| 1        | Festivals  |
| 2        | Concerts   |
--------------------------
```

For your checkboxes you could have something that searches through countries(Were are the festivals / concerts) or a genre(rock, house, etc). I think this would be better to specify under **radio buttons** instead of checkboxes, maybe even another `<select>` option

Example of tables for countries:

```
------------------------------------
| country_id | country_name       |
| 1          | The Netherlands    |
| 2          | Great-Brittain     |
------------------------------------
```

Example of tables for genre:

```
--------------------------
| genre_id | genre_name |
| 1        | Rock       |
| 2        | House      |
--------------------------
```

Now you can dynamically create `<options>` inside your select using SQL queries.

When doing so you can also continue to use a trigger for a jQuery function/JavaScript function/AJAX call on for example the `.change`(jQuery listener) of your `<select>`.

When doing an AJAX call(sending parameters/variables to another .PHP file which will give results back) you can put every outcome of your Query(Fetched results) inside a `<option>` in a `<select multiple>`, if you put it in a `<select multiple>` you can easily see all results

I hope I have steered you in something of the right direction.